# Duplicated add to cart button issue in woocommerce_single_product_summary hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Trying to turn the add to cart button into a download link on a Woocommerce site *(for free downloadable items)*.

The code I have set up below does that, but it is also duplicating the add to cart button. So I end up with the file download link + an additional add to cart button.

What am I missing?

Here is that code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'itl_woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

/*
 * replace WooCommerce add-to-cart button with download link when product is 
downloadable & free
 */

function itl_woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_downloadable('yes') ) {
        if ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->product_type . 
 '_add_to_cart' );
        } else {
            $downloads = $product->get_files();
            foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
                echo '<p class="download-link"><a href="' . esc_url( 
$download['file'] ) . '">' . $download['name'] . '</a></p>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->product_type . '_add_to_cart' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revisited, corrected, compact and tested your code. So now its working for WC version 3+:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customizing_single_add_to_cart', 1 );
function customizing_single_add_to_cart(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function(){
        global $product;
        if ( $product->is_downloadable() && $product->get_price() <= 0 )
            foreach( $product->get_downloads() as $key => $download )
                echo '<p class="download-link"><a href="' . esc_url( $download['file'] ) . '">' . $download['name'] . '</a></p>';
        else
            woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
    }, 30);
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works *(in WooCommerce version 3+)*